# Добавить -webkit-linear-gradient в строку html таблицы

Tags: html, градиент, цвета

нужно вставить градиент не на всю строку, а с 3 по 5 столбец 
надо чтоб было так

сейчас [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
что мне надо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>---</th>
            <th>---</th>
            <th>First</th>
      <th>Second</th>
            <th>Three</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>not gradient</td>
            <td>not gradient</td>
            <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

* {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;border-collapse:collapse;}

table { 
width:100%;
}

th, td {
         border: 2px solid black;
         text-align: center;
}

tbody { 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #729fcf 10%, #93971c 10% 20%, #16eab7 20% 35%, #427b70 35%  45%, #861d53 45% 60%, #729fcf 60% 80%, green 0);

    background-attachment:fixed;}

thead tr, thead th { background:transparent; }
```

ссылка на пример

http://jsfiddle.net/cpLuye4d/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо применить градиент к строке, начиная с 3-его столбца, а вы применяете, начиная с 1-ого. Для начала, стоит добавить в градиент прозрачность до 3-его столбца, например, так:

```
<style>
tbody { 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 40%,
        #729fcf 40% 45%, #93971c 45% 50%, #16eab7 50% 65%, #427b70 65% 75%, #861d53 75% 90%, #729fcf 90% 95%, green 0);
}
</style>
```

Но как угадать, сколько именно % ширины займут 1-ый и 2-ой столбцы? Задать это самим:

```
<style>
th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1), 
th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2) { 
    width: 20%;
}
</style>
```

P.S. сейчас всё ещё надо добавлять префикс браузера к таким свойствам, как linear-gradient?

Comment: Могли бы вы подсказать пжл, если другие варианты сделат такое, без linear-gradient ?

Comment: вариантов много: закрашивать по отдельности td; добавить в td элементы с разной шириной и закрашивать их; использовать картинки\svg в качестве background; использовать :before и :after...